# automatic wmode to direct or transparant

Tags: flash, wmode

I publish Flash games that's sometimes only load with wmode="direct" instead of wmode="transparant".

How should I load the right wmode automatically ?

Here is my static code :

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="anim"
name="anim" width="100%" height="100%"> <param name="movie"
value="thegame.swf" /><param name="wmode" value="direct"><param
name="quality" value="high" /><param name="allowScriptAccess"
value="always" /> <embed src="thegame.swf" id="anim" name="anim"
quality="high" allowScriptAccess="always"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%"
wmode="direct"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /> </object>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Who forced you to use a wmode and not another ?! You can edit your HTML code as you like, and then you have just to compile your SWF ...

Comment: I search for an autmatic way because of the number of games added. Some games only work in direct wmode and most of the others in transparant wmode.
I just search a way to catch if wmode=direct is needed or not for a .swf file.

Comment: I don't think that there is an "automatic" way to detect the appropriate wmode for an SWF, but what I know is that the "direct" wmode is used with an SWF that uses Stage Video or Stage 3D ...